# Ceph OSD crashes

Tags: centos, failover, ceph, object-storage

I am looking for a solution that can bring up our 3 ceph OSD which are down. According to the log I can see the following output that I guess it is because of OSD are full.

At the moment 3 osd of 4 are down and the ceph cluster is also down and I have no clue about the following error.

```
   root@cephosd02 ~]# /usr/bin/ceph-osd -f --cluster ceph --id 1 --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph
    /home/jenkins-build/build/workspace/ceph-build/ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_DIST/centos7/DIST/centos7/MACHINE_SIZE/gigantic/release/15.2.13/rpm/el7/BUILD/ceph-15.2.13/src/os/bluestore/AvlAllocator.cc: In function 'virtual void AvlAllocator::_add_to_tree(uint64_t, uint64_t)' thread 7f633fca3bc0 time 2021-11-28T12:02:33.118576+0330
    /home/jenkins-build/build/workspace/ceph-build/ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_DIST/centos7/DIST/centos7/MACHINE_SIZE/gigantic/release/15.2.13/rpm/el7/BUILD/ceph-15.2.13/src/os/bluestore/AvlAllocator.cc: 60: FAILED ceph_assert(size != 0)
     ceph version 15.2.13 (c44bc49e7a57a87d84dfff2a077a2058aa2172e2) octopus (stable)
     1: (ceph::__ceph_assert_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)+0x14c) [0x55b6ed7219a3]
     2: (()+0x4deb6b) [0x55b6ed721b6b]
     3: (AvlAllocator::_add_to_tree(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x2db9) [0x55b6edd9af89]
     4: (AvlAllocator::init_add_free(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x69) [0x55b6edd9e8d9]
     5: (BlueStore::_open_alloc()+0x1d3) [0x55b6edc61ad3]
     6: (BlueStore::_open_db_and_around(bool)+0xa7) [0x55b6edc7a507]
     7: (BlueStore::_mount(bool, bool)+0x5c2) [0x55b6edcc6ba2]
     8: (OSD::init()+0x35d) [0x55b6ed82f1bd]
     9: (main()+0x1b5e) [0x55b6ed78372e]
     10: (__libc_start_main()+0xf5) [0x7f633caf5555]
     11: (()+0x575dd5) [0x55b6ed7b8dd5]
    * Caught signal (Aborted) **
     in thread 7f633fca3bc0 thread_name:ceph-osd
    2021-11-28T12:02:33.125+0330 7f633fca3bc0 -1 /home/jenkins-build/build/workspace/ceph-build/ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_DIST/centos7/DIST/centos7/MACHINE_SIZE/gigantic/release/15.2.13/rpm/el7/BUILD/ceph-15.2.13/src/os/bluestore/AvlAllocator.cc: In function 'virtual void AvlAllocator::_add_to_tree(uint64_t, uint64_t)' thread 7f633fca3bc0 time 2021-11-28T12:02:33.118576+0330
    /home/jenkins-build/build/workspace/ceph-build/ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_ARCH/x86_64/AVAILABLE_DIST/centos7/DIST/centos7/MACHINE_SIZE/gigantic/release/15.2.13/rpm/el7/BUILD/ceph-15.2.13/src/os/bluestore/AvlAllocator.cc: 60: FAILED ceph_assert(size != 0)
    
     ceph version 15.2.13 (c44bc49e7a57a87d84dfff2a077a2058aa2172e2) octopus (stable)
     1: (ceph::__ceph_assert_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)+0x14c) [0x55b6ed7219a3]
     2: (()+0x4deb6b) [0x55b6ed721b6b]
     3: (AvlAllocator::_add_to_tree(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x2db9) [0x55b6edd9af89]
     4: (AvlAllocator::init_add_free(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x69) [0x55b6edd9e8d9]
     5: (BlueStore::_open_alloc()+0x1d3) [0x55b6edc61ad3]
     6: (BlueStore::_open_db_and_around(bool)+0xa7) [0x55b6edc7a507]
     7: (BlueStore::_mount(bool, bool)+0x5c2) [0x55b6edcc6ba2]
     8: (OSD::init()+0x35d) [0x55b6ed82f1bd]
     9: (main()+0x1b5e) [0x55b6ed78372e]
     10: (__libc_start_main()+0xf5) [0x7f633caf5555]
     11: (()+0x575dd5) [0x55b6ed7b8dd5]
    
     ceph version 15.2.13 (c44bc49e7a57a87d84dfff2a077a2058aa2172e2) octopus (stable)
     1: (()+0xf630) [0x7f633dd16630]
     2: (gsignal()+0x37) [0x7f633cb09387]
     3: (abort()+0x148) [0x7f633cb0aa78]
     4: (ceph::__ceph_assert_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)+0x19b) [0x55b6ed7219f2]
     5: (()+0x4deb6b) [0x55b6ed721b6b]
     6: (AvlAllocator::_add_to_tree(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x2db9) [0x55b6edd9af89]
     7: (AvlAllocator::init_add_free(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x69) [0x55b6edd9e8d9]
     8: (BlueStore::_open_alloc()+0x1d3) [0x55b6edc61ad3]
     9: (BlueStore::_open_db_and_around(bool)+0xa7) [0x55b6edc7a507]
     10: (BlueStore::_mount(bool, bool)+0x5c2) [0x55b6edcc6ba2]
     11: (OSD::init()+0x35d) [0x55b6ed82f1bd]
     12: (main()+0x1b5e) [0x55b6ed78372e]
     13: (__libc_start_main()+0xf5) [0x7f633caf5555]
     14: (()+0x575dd5) [0x55b6ed7b8dd5]
    2021-11-28T12:02:33.133+0330 7f633fca3bc0 -1 * Caught signal (Aborted) **
     in thread 7f633fca3bc0 thread_name:ceph-osd
    
     ceph version 15.2.13 (c44bc49e7a57a87d84dfff2a077a2058aa2172e2) octopus (stable)
     1: (()+0xf630) [0x7f633dd16630]
     2: (gsignal()+0x37) [0x7f633cb09387]
     3: (abort()+0x148) [0x7f633cb0aa78]
     4: (ceph::__ceph_assert_fail(char const*, char const*, int, char
```

Comment: How full were the OSDs? It can be very difficult to bring back up full OSDs, if there's a chance it's if you add more OSDs to the cluster, and even then it requires manual intervention. Never let your cluster fill up entirely.

Comment: @eblock,  Actually I don't know how full they were. I come to office and saw they are down it's my fault for sure.

Comment: The log files on the mon daemons could answer that, it probably also contains the warnings about (near)full OSDs.